# javascript accessing newly created object

Tags: javascript

If

```
function foos(){alert(this)}
x=new foos() which is==={foo();}//as this keyword points to Object object
```

so than i can say foos as the method of that new object but when i do this

```
x.foos();//after the object is initialized,it dont work at all why?
```

Comment: Your code snippet does not compile. Can you provide one that does?

Comment: @janDvorak if u just try to compile {foo();} thats an error but if u do {foo:(function(){})()} that really works

Comment: Not just `{foo();}`; I'm complaining about `which is ===`, which is not valid javascript and I'm not sure how to parse it as english.

Answer (score 0):

The code creates an instance of `foos` on which `foos` is not defined as a property on that object.

If you want to add a property on an object try something like:

```
function foos(){
  this.myProp = "Hello";
}

var x = new foos();

alert(x.myProp);
```

If you want to add a method to an object use:

```
foos.prototype.myFunc = function(){
  alert(this.myProp);
};

x.myFunc(); //alerts Hello
```

Comment: i disagree.js engine executes the function entering the object which means x=new foo()==={foo();} .this is the real fact because x={method:(function(){})()} gets executed.

Comment: @MaizerePathak you might want to prove that *real fact* by some reference? Otherwise it's just what you're assuming.

Comment: @Kevin Bowersox which proves that js engine gets within the object ,once it gets entered everything within there are the properties of that object.

Comment: @Yoshi i have given the reference new keyword creates an empty object within which the function gets executed therefore the this keyword within the function points to Object object

Comment: @MaizerePathak yes its an object, but not an object that contains the `foos` property.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/Y4Z5f/

Comment: @MaizerePathak *within which the function gets executed...* that's not correct. The constructor function (`foos` in this example) gets the newly created object as it's context.

Comment: But your not going to access the constructor function by simply calling 'x.foos' it needs to be 'x.constructor' which is the constructor property of the object that points to the foos constructor.

Comment: @KevinBowersox unless, of course, `foos.prototype.constructor` has been modified.

Answer (score 0):

'foos' is the constructor function and it will not be part of the newly object methods,
if u want to add methods u can use it like this:

```
function MyClass() { }

MyClass.prototype.foos = function () {
    alert(this);
}
```

and then:

```
var x = new MyClass();
x.foos();
```

Comment: no u are wrong.I agree with what u said but disagree with what u think.